# TSlint lists Problems in VSCode for Git Diff files

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-diff, tslint

#### My Problem

When I compare two versions of a file with VS Code and the built-in Git features TSLint does not ignore the revisions but marks the errors. Since the diff files are located in `AppData\Local\Temp` on Windows the path checking fails and other things as well.

However, most annoying is not the red line in the file view but that they are listed in the *Problem Panel* and I get like **20+ problems** just because opening one file revision and they won't go away until I reopen VS Code, so they add up during time.

That makes the panel useless for me, since I see lots of pseudo-problems, I won't notice an actual problem.

#### What I tried

I tried in my `settings.json`

```
"tslint.exclude": ["**/AppData/**"]
```

but that didn't work out.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears that this is an issue with the GitLens extension which will be fixed with the upcoming version:

> this issue has been fixed in the GitLens 9 release which will be coming very soon.
>
> ~ *eamodio*

(Source: https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/430#issuecomment-440731347)